# How to find attribute values using regular expression with Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: regex, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

The HTML is as follows:

```html
<div class="item link-color-1 
     automated link-track logout-link" 
     data-track-category="Logout" 
     data-track-action="Logout from /myaccount/mymoney/cashier" 
     data-data-automated-function="clickTracker"> logout </div>
```

To find the x path of a link, tried something like: //*[contains(@data-track-category='Logout']. But its not working. Please help.

Comment: Do you really need to use Regular Expressions? I've posted an answer, not sure it will help since i can't see what language you need this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to find the element itself (and not the value of the attribute as your question title implies), you could always use CSS (its my selector of choice over XPath).

You have not indicated which language bindings you use, so this is how I would find it in Ruby by using only the data-track-category attribute to select the element:

```
@driver.find_element(:css => "[data-track-category='Logout']")
```

Of course, the same applies across all the bindings. Just use the value `"[data-track-category='Logout']"` for your CSS method.

Answer (score 0):

You can always store the given element in a `WebElement` and then using the `getAttribute()` method. You can find the documentation [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29)

```java
WebElement myDiv = driver.findElement(By.className("logout-link"));
String attributeValue = myDiv.getAttribute("data-track-category");
```

This should work on Java. Not sure that's the language you are looking for or if you must use regex for it.